# Tune SVM in R - Dependent variable has wrong type

Tags: r, svm

I'm using `svm` from `e1071` for a dataset like this:

```
sdewey <- svm(x = as.matrix(trainS), 
              y = trainingSmall$DEWEY,
              type="C-classification")
```

That works just fine, but when I try to tune the cost and gamma like this:

```
svm_tune <- tune(svm, train.x=as.matrix(trainS), train.y=trainingSmall$DEWEY, type="C-classification",    ranges=list(cost=10^(-1:6), gamma=1^(-1:1)))
```

I get this error:

> Error in tune(svm, train.x = as.matrix(trainS), train.y =
>   trainingSmall$DEWEY,  : Dependent variable has wrong type!

The structure of my training data is this, but with many more lines:

```
'data.frame':   1000 obs. of  1542 variables:
 $ women.prisoners                                  : int  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ reformatories.for.women                          : int  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ women                                            : int  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ criminal.justice                                 : int  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ soccer                                           : int  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ coal.mines.and.mining                            : int  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ coal                                             : int  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ engineering.geology                              : int  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ family.violence                                  : int  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

It is a multi-class problem.
I'm not sure of how I could solve this or if there are other ways of finding out the optimal value for the cost and gamma parameters.

[Here is an example of my data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7JXHHQ_-5IVZWdPS3ZCcGZ4Y0k), and `trainS` is that data without the first 4 columns (DEWEY, D1, D2 and D3)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require(e1071)

trainingSmall<-read.csv("trainingSmallExtra.csv")

sdewey <- svm(x      = as.matrix(trainingSmall[,4:nrow(trainingSmall)]), 
              y      = trainingSmall$DEWEY,
              type   = "C-classification",
              kernel = "linear" # same as no kernel
              )
```

This works because `svm` has automatically converted `DEWEY` to a factor.

The `tune` model failed because, being that it is made for user customization, it relies on you to supply the correct data type. Since `DEWEY` was integer instead of `factor` it failed. We can fix this:

```
trainingSmall$DEWEY <- as.factor(trainingSmall$DEWEY)

svm_tune <- tune(svm, train.x = as.matrix(trainingSmall[,4:nrow(trainingSmall)]), 
                      train.y = trainingSmall$DEWEY, # the way I'm formatting your  
                      kernel  = "linear",            # code is Google's R style
                      type    = "C-classification",    
                      ranges  = list(
                                      cost  = 10^(-1:6), 
                                      gamma =  1^(-1:1)
                                    )
                 )
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked just fine. I realized that I left the type="linear" flag which doesn't make sense since it's not neccesary to find cost and gamma for that particular type (I was trying to see if linear worked worst/better than RBF). I edited the question to fix that.